# Grails - Open MySQL and Apache Server from Project without Xampp\Wamp

Tags: mysql, apache, tomcat, grails

I am building a Grails Project that uses MySQL for manipulating database entries and execute CRUD examples.

For the MySQL server to be active, I use XAMPP Control Panel and I must have Apache and MySQL opened in the XAMPP Control Panel in order to establish a connection between Grails and my MySQL Database.

[image]

The Grails Project starts Tomcat server itself everytime I run my project, and I dont know how I can achieve that with Apache and MySQL, so that I wont have to use the XAMPP Panel every time. When the WAR is created, I should be able to create the connection from within the project, without the need of a Server Panel like Xampp or Wamp.

[image]

I would like to find a way to start Apache and MySQL server from inside the Grails Project. Any ideas?

Comment: You will not be able to start a MySQL server from within the Grails application. You could do it with an in memory database though (H2 for example).

Comment: MySQL cannot be configured as an in-memory DB?